# Boolean value isn't being uploaded to DynamoDB as a boolean on PHP

Tags: php, boolean, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to upload an item to my DynamoDB table. One of the attributes is a Boolean type.

I'm using this code to upload the item:

```
$item = $client->putItem(array(
    'TableName' => 'Table',
    'Item' => array(
        'name' => array('S' => $name),
        'status' => array('B' => 'TRUE')
    )
));
```

Every thing looks fine when I'm running it, no fatal errors or warnings, but when I check the table, I see this value instead of `true`:

```
VFJVRQ==
```

What can I do to fix this and show `true` on my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`B`** represents Binary data type on DynamoDB

**`BOOL`** represents Boolean data type on DynamoDB

```
'status' => array('BOOL' => true)
```